# How configure jasperreports 5 with maven?

Tags: maven, jasper-reports, ireport

I installed iReport-5.0.1. I would like to configure JasperReports with Maven. My POM file looks like this:

```
<dependency>

    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>

</dependency>


<dependency>

    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1</version>

</dependency>

<dependency>

    <groupId>poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.1-FINAL</version>

</dependency>
```

I guess my settings are wrong. Could anyone help me?

Comment: This is not complete pom.xml. Why are you guessing than this is wrong?

Comment: I think you're wrong because I checked this post: [Exception java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError while running Groovy in Eclipse Juno](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738732/exception-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-while-running-groovy-in-eclipse)
This message is returned to me: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor, but class was expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved with:

---------- pom.xml ----------

```
<project [ default xml namespace details.. ]>

    [..project-details..]
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-digester3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
            <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
            <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
            <version>1.7R4</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
            <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
            <version>2.0b5</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-javaflow</artifactId>
            <version>1209105</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.14</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.17</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>

        </dependency>

        [..other package dependency..]
    </dependencies>

</project>
```