# JBoss Modules for large number of jar dependencies HOW TO

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, jasper-reports, jboss-modules

I'm trying to figure out how to make my WARs lighter by putting JasperReports, Apache POI and other heavy libs directly to JBoss AS by using [JBoss Modules](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Introduction).

Now, Jasper uses many many libraries to generate PDF or XLS files as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15477800/305121). Our templates are pretty old and we are stuck with old jasper version 3.7.1 which of course uses older versions of libraries such as commons which are already present on JBoss AS 7.1.1 modules.

How can I make one "big" module which will contain all jars used by Jasper and keep other parts of application using newer modules?

Putting all jars into separate directories seems so much work without guaranteed success, can we put everything into one module without creating package alike directories?

Comment: I think with a maven project if you have all the common libraries defined in the parent pom you could then only have module specific libs defined in the individual modules/projects. I am not sure if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We started with JBoss modules recently and wrote a small plugin for Maven that generates module folders with module.xmls based on XML descriptors. The plugin is called [smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin](http://www.smartics.eu/smartics-jboss-modules-maven-plugin) and you'll find additional information about it at the [project's blog](http://www.smartics.de/projects/productivity-a-ware/smartics-jboss-modules).

We just started to work with it, but it already makes the process of synchronization between the POM and the module.xml (plus directory structure) for our projects very easy.

The downside of this approach is that you have to learn an additional XML descriptor and have to configure an additional Maven plugin.

If you want to give it a try, the plugin is licensed under Apache License 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

The creation of JBoss modules for external libraries can be automated through maven as explained in another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289813/best-practice-for-loading-3rd-party-jars-in-jboss-as7-standalone-deployment) on SO. The author has posted a [GitHub project](https://github.com/ringerc/as7-eclipselink-integration) too. This can lessen the pain in managing lots of transitive dependencies.