# IncompatibleClassChangeError: class ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface ClassVisitor as super class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, maven-3

I have built a web application using spring-mvc and mongodb as database. I used maven3 to build the application.

Project builds successfully but when application starts I am getting the following error in the logs due to which my application does not start. This used to work few months ago.

> Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class
>   org.springframework.core.type.classreading.ClassMetadataReadingVisitor
>   has interface org.springframework.asm.ClassVisitor as super class

Please let me know if any pointers or if you guys need more information.

Comment: Please refer to my answer in below link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11738732/exception-java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-while-running-groovy-in-eclipse/58131989#58131989

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This error happens when the loaded class i.e. `ClassMetadataReadingVisitor` does not respect the contract of inherited abstract class or interface i.e. `ClassVisitor`.

Looks like at load time different versions of the above classes are getting loaded in your case.

Seems you have new spring-core jar and old spring-asm jar in your application. `ClassMetadataReadingVisitor` class is getting loaded from **spring-core** and `ClassVisitor` from **spring-asm**.

Please check using maven `dependency:tree` command to see the dependent jars.

Comment: Yes i see different versions of spring jars. The mongodb dependencies are pulling the latest jars. How should i resolve the issue?

Comment: Since mongo dependencies need latest spring you also bump up your spring dependencies. But you said it used to work in the past which means may be mongo jars has not defined any version for its spring dependency so pulled the latest automatically. Check the mongo jars pom.

Comment: Thanks for the poiner. Yes its mongo jars which does not define the version dependency. For now I have used the latest spring version.

Answer (score 45):

In spring version > 3.2.0, you no longer need to explicitly include `spring-asm` since it has already been included in `spring-core`.

Remove `spring-asm` from your build definition and ensure that `spring-core` is there.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/migration-3.2.html#migration-3.2-inline-asm

Comment: It helped me to remove `cglib`, which depends on `asm`.

Answer (score 8):

This error usually shows up when incomptiable versions of jars are used, for example `spring-asm` and `spring-core`. Have a look at [forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133341](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?133341)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and faced it by deleting my `spring-data-jpa` dependency from `pom.xml`

It's already included in the `spring-core` dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Update for those moving to versions above 3.1.x ... as made clear by [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800004/why-is-there-no-spring-asm-3-2-4-release-jar) there is no longer a separate `spring-asm`, so it would be better to exclude `spring-asm` altogether, once you're at Spring version 3.2.x