# Why is there no spring-asm-3.2.4.RELEASE jar?

Tags: spring, maven, jar, software-distribution

I'm trying to build a complete Spring Framework distribution for version 3.2.4.RELEASE without using maven (just the spring jars) and managed to manually get all jars except for spring-asm.

Spring-asm stops at [version 3.1.4](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-asm). Why is that?

I have older spring distributions up to 3.1.1 (those for which you had a zip file, not forced to use maven) and all have the same spring-asm jar inside, with the same version.

Why is there no spring-asm-3.2.4.RELEASE jar?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Here is from [release notes](http://spring.io/blog/2012/09/12/spring-framework-3-2-m2-released) for 3.2

> we've eliminated the dedicated spring-asm jar in M2 in favor of including org.springframework.asm classes directly in spring-core