# Is there a dependency can replace the org.springframework.asm?

Tags: maven

When I add dependency `asm` to my `pom.xml`, I find the org.springframework.asm

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

I click the red bulb to update the Maven Repository Indices:

[image]

But it is too slow.

So, if there is a dependency for replacing it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800004/why-is-there-no-spring-asm-3-2-4-release-jar check this

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to add the library replace your method is:

1. Search the google or in mvnrepository http://mvnrepository.com/search?q=org.springframework.asm to download the `jar` file.
2. Copy the `jar` to the `WEB-INF/lib`
3. Then add the `jar` file as Library

This can add a repository quickly rather than your slow method.

Comment: or simply add to your pom mvn repository as <repository> ... that will get rid out of you all copy paste operations

Comment: @Reborn You should know the question is pom.xml.

Comment: did i mention something wrong? https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html ( first source code)

Comment: just simply add this https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public/

Comment: @Reborn you see his pom.xml, he add the dependency like you.

Comment: and you see, that he cant find version. Check from which repository mvnrepository takes dependency. It tells Alfresco Public, which means he needs to add artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/public as <repository>. Why this solution is better? As i stated before - you save time on copy/pasting jars and so on

Comment: @Reborn, Why can't? every donwload jar from mvcrepostory have the suffix shows the version.