# How to find which dependency current jar file is referred?

Tags: java, maven

In Eclipse, expand current project in project explorer,

click `Java Resources` -> `libraries` -> `Maven Dependencies`

And I found there are two jar files which in different version, i.e.:

```
commons-lang-2.1.jar
and
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
```

but from `pom.xml`, I cannot tell where `commons-lang-2.1.jar` come from as it must required by one of the artifacts. But it is too much trouble to check `pom` file from each artifact...

I heard of `dependency-tree` can work something similar but don't know how to make it work under this situation. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Actually maven has its own library folder and it is capable of download missing libraries from internet when compiling.

Comment: @libik The question is what's requiring those versions.

Comment: Show in Eclipse. First click on the pom.xml file and than on the Tab "Dependency hierarchy" should give you information from where such elements are comming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Look for the two instances of commons-lang and see what requires them.

That said, the two versions aren't compatible, and can live in the same application:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html

[See this answer of mine regarding deciphering the tree output.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22357323/438992) The nutshell is that indented libraries are dependencies of the non-indented library above it: a dependency tree.

Answer (score 2):

execute

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

if you have very giant dependency tree and hard to read you can use

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=org.apache.commons:commons-lang3
```

to just include occurrence of this artifact

from your pom.xml it will list out all the dependencies being pulled directly or indirectly, and put the [`<exclusion>`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html) to avoid consumption of non desired library