# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.session.hazelcast.PrincipalNameExtractor

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, hazelcast, spring-session

I am trying to configure spring session backed by hazelcast for spring security oauth2 client application.

I followed below link to configure hazelcast.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/java-hazelcast.html

However, classes annotated with @SpringBootTest started failing due to below error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.springframework.session.hazelcast.PrincipalNameExtractor has interface com.hazelcast.query.extractor.ValueExtractor as super class
```

My pom.xml of spring boot 2.5 application contain below two new dependencies for hazelcast configuration

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
            <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-session-hazelcast</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

As per below stackoverflow post , issue seems to be that ValueExtractor is available for two different versions in maven dependencies
[IncompatibleClassChangeError: class ClassMetadataReadingVisitor has interface ClassVisitor as super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209623/incompatibleclasschangeerror-class-classmetadatareadingvisitor-has-interface-cl)

Hence, I checked maven dependencies and can see that PrincipalNameExtractor is available from 2.5 version of spring-session-hazelcast while ValueExtractor is available from 4.2 version on com.hazelcast. However,
spring-session-hazelcast is using 3.12.12 version of com.hazelcast for compilation.

So should I use 3.12.12 version of com.hazelcast to resolve this issue or am in misinterpreting the issue? I prefer to use latest version.

Comment: starting from v2.4.0, you can use Hazelcast v4.x with Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor and Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository. Here is a guide covering both versions: https://guides.hazelcast.org/spring-session-hazelcast

Comment: @ozcan Thanks for the post. This post resolved all maven dependencies & fixed all failing testcases.

Comment: good to hear that worked. Posting as an answer also to make it visible.

Comment: @Ozcan could you plz also share any link which shows the configuration changes required to make hazelcast work with spring oauth2 client and spring security 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from spring-sessions v2.4.0, you can use Hazelcast v4.x with configuring `Hazelcast4PrincipalNameExtractor` and `Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository` for the session repository. The only difference is the class names with `4` indicator. That is, `HazelcastIndexedSessionRepository` becomes 4.x compatible with `Hazelcast4IndexedSessionRepository`.

Here is a guide covering both versions: https://guides.hazelcast.org/spring-session-hazelcast/